# Методы объекта ES5

Tags: javascript, функции

Можно ли обратиться к **методу** объекта изнутри через `binding identifier`, как во второй функции?

```js
let obj = {
  funcFirst() {
    console.log(funcFirst);
  },
  funcSecond: function funcSecond() {
    console.log(funcSecond);
  }
}

obj.funcSecond();
obj.funcFirst();
```

Comment: Можно. Просто у вас опечатка в слове funcFirst и нужно использовать this

Comment: @AlexeyTen, я исправил. через `this` это и так понятно, а вот как через `binding identifier` которая видна внутри `FunctionExpression`?

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный, нет нельзя.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Можно ли обратиться к методу объекта изнутри через binding identifier, как во второй функции?

Нет нельзя.

---

[MethodDefinition](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#prod-MethodDefinition) в отличие от [FunctionExpression](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#prod-FunctionExpression) не подразумевает добавление в создаваемый EnvironmentRecord ссылки на создаваемую функцию с указанным именем.

В этом можно убедиться посмотрев описания Runtime Semantics в соответствующих разделах.

У [MethodDefinition](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#prod-MethodDefinition) вместо строк

```
Perform envRec.CreateImmutableBinding(name, false).
...
Perform envRec.InitializeBinding(name, closure).
```

Стоит добавление свойства в объект, например:

```
Let desc be the PropertyDescriptor{[[Value]]: methodDef.[[Closure]], [[Writable]]: true, [[Enumerable]]: enumerable, [[Configurable]]: true}.
Return ? DefinePropertyOrThrow(object, methodDef.[[Key]], desc).
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно

```js
let obj = {
  funcFirts() {
    console.log(this.funcFirts);
  },
  funcSecond: function f() {
    console.log(f);
  }
}

obj.funcSecond();
obj.funcFirts();
```

Comment: я же не зря привел пример с функцией. мне необходим такой же эффект.